# Firebird / DELPHI - Nested transactions not supported

Tags: delphi

I can't change a record in Firebird. I get the message
"Nested transaction not supported"
I have a system that uses the Sql Server 7 database,
i couldn't make it work with firebird, because when one
table is changed, I find the above message. In other words,the following code gives the error:

```
DataBase1.StartTransaction;
Try
Begin
Query1.Open;
Query1.RequestLive := True;
Query1.Sql.Clear;
Query1.Sql.Add('Select * from Tab'); // returns 5 registers
Query1.Open;
Query1.Edit;
Query1.FieldByName('Name').AsString:='New data';
Query1.Post; // it appears the error message 
file.Base1.Commit;
end;
except
file.Base1.RollBack;
end;
```

I use firebird and IBManager to create DB and tables
Any help?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by " Sql Server 7"?  " Sql Server" usually refers to Microsoft Sql Server, which is nothing to do withh Firebird.

Comment: @MartynA: Well, both are database servers. I understand the question as that the nested transactions do work fine with SQL Server, but do not when using a Firebird server.

Comment: @UweRaabe:  Thanks, you could be right.  But what are the random backslashes about?

Comment: @MartynA: The previous two posts also contain backslashes. Very odd. A coincidence?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `Query1.Open` followed by `Query1.SQL.Clear` immediately closes the query again. Rather than just randomly throw code around, read what you've written and see if it makes sense. `Query1.SQL.Text  := ` + your SQL statement, followed by the call to `Open`, is all you need. Remove everything above the `Query1.Edit` and replace it with the two lines I just gave you and seel if the problem goes away. Also remove the backslash in your SQL, because it's invalid SQL (which has nothing to do with Delphi, it's invalid in general).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Could it be something to do with SO's changeover to CommonMark?

Comment: @MartynA: That was my first thought as well.

Comment: @KenWhite, Actually, I already knew that. What makes you think I didn't?